# htlatex with pdfpages package inserts random images

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex, latex2html

I am attempting to generate an HTML output via

```
htlatex <filename>
```

but when the `pgfpages` package is included I am getting some random images before *and* after the content.  The resulting **HTML** viewed in Safari looks like:

[image]

I looked at `pdfpages.sty` and see that there is an `\AtBeginDocument` but don't see how that inserts these random images before the content. Furthermore, did not find a `\AtEndDocument` so can't understand how anything is happening after the content is processed.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
   % \includepdf{foo.pdf}% Cover page
    
    Some content following cover page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you use pdfpages just to include some one page pdf file, or do you want to use some more advanced options?

Comment: @michal.h21: I am using `pdfpages` to include the cover page of the book. But, as the above MWE demonstrates just including the package (without using it) results in the random images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pdfpages` is obviously one of packages which causes `tex4ht` to fail just with loading. some other example of such package is `fontspec`. only solution is to prevent usage of such packages when `tex4ht` is loaded and to provide alternative definitions for macros used in the document.

To simplify this process, I created simple package, called `alternative4ht.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{alternative4ht}

\newcommand{\altusepackage}[2][]{%
    \ifx\HCode\relax%
    \usepackage[#1]{#2}%
    \else%
    \IfFileExists{#2-alt4ht.sty}{%
      \usepackage[#1]{#2-alt4ht}%
    }{\typeout{alternative4ht: no patch file for #2}}
    \fi%
}
\endinput
```

one command is defined, `\altusepackage`, which loads package with normal LaTeX, but with `tex4ht` it loads alternative definitions or it does nothing if such alternative doesn't exist.

You can modify your source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
   %\includepdf{foo.pdf}% Cover page

    Some content following cover page.
\end{document}
```

you can provide definition for `\includepdf` in file `pdfpages-alt4ht.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pdfpages-alt4ht}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\includepdf[2][]{%
    \includegraphics{#2}
}

\endinput
```

and you will need to add support for pdf image inclusion with custom config file, `peter.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{graphics*}  
         {pdf}  
         {\Needs{"convert \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                               \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}%  
          \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}%  
          \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
         }  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

now you can compile the document with:

```
htlatex <filename> peter
```

and the resulting html is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" /> 
<!-- html,xhtml --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2014-10-06 09:55:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" ><img 
src="foo.png" alt="pict"  
 />
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   Some content following cover page. </p> 
</body></html>
```